# Changing height and width on the LI elements of the horizontal list

Tags: html, css

I am making  a little color code legend and can't figure out how to make all my `<li>` items the same height as the `<div>` they are in and widen them out so that they fill the whole `<div>`, not just the area around the `<label>` text. Or maybe someone has another suggestion to make it look better?

```css
#navlist li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#navcontainer {
  background-color: White;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: gray;
}

#legendTitle {
  background-color: #ABAAC1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: White;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gvRowReqIncomplete {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
  color: Red;
}

.gvRowReqAlmostComplete {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
  color: Black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gvRowReqComplete {
  background-color: #ededf2;
  color: Black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gvRowSubReq {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  color: Black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
  <div id="legendTitle">Color Legend</div>
  <br />
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li><label Class="gvRowReqComplete">Complete</label></li>
    <li> <label Class="gvRowReqAlmostComplete">Partially Complete </label></li>
    <li>
      <Label Class="gvRowReqIncomplete">Incomplete Request</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Label Class="gvRowSubReq">Response</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZCKm/)

Comment: I don't see any height or width styles in your code. Also, `inline` elements have no width or height. You'd need to make them `display:block`. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JZCKm/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<li>` and `<label>` elements are inline, so neither height nor width have any impact. I set them to `display:block`. I also floated `<li>` elements left and set their height and width.

```css
#navlist {
  list-style: none;
}

#navlist li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
}

#navlist li label {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#navcontainer {
  background-color: White;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: gray;
}

#legendTitle {
  background-color: #ABAAC1;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: White;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gvRowReqIncomplete {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
  color: Red;
}

.gvRowReqAlmostComplete {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
  color: Black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gvRowReqComplete {
  background-color: #ededf2;
  color: Black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gvRowSubReq {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  color: Black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
  <div id="legendTitle">Color Legend</div>
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li>
      <label Class="gvRowReqComplete">Complete</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label Class="gvRowReqAlmostComplete">Partially Complete</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Label Class="gvRowReqIncomplete">Incomplete Request</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Label Class="gvRowSubReq">Response</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing the label tags and moving each class to the li, like this:

```
<li Class="gvRowReqComplete">Complete</li>
```

Then if you change the li display to inline-block you can specify a set height for them. You can also center the text of each li.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/SFZJv/2/

I added a grey background for reference.

Comment: This is nice and clean! However, consider browser compatibility of `inline-block` for your particular project. http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Comment: Incidentally, `table-cell` not supported by IE 6 or 7. Typical, huh. Nice for modern browsers, though.